Two people receive orders at the same time in laravel
My problem is that I am creating a shipper application. When two people receive the same order, both of their amounts will be deducted. How can I do this if only one person can receive orders at a time in Laravel?
$cacheKeyOrder = "accept_order_" . $request['order_id'] . "_shipper_" . $dm->id;

        if (Cache::has($cacheKeyOrder)) {
            Cache::forget($cacheKeyOrder);
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    ['code' => 'order', 'message' => 'Đơn hàng đã được tài xế khác xác nhận trước !']
                ]
            ], 203);
        } else {
            Cache::put($cacheKeyOrder, true);

        }    


Show the code where after receiving order amounts will be deducted.

question needs improvement.  "Two customers receive the same order". what does this even mean?

"My problem is that I am creating a shipper application." that sucks man
